Basic configuration of Solr with Docker on Plesk
Due to Plesk requirements, if you need Solr and Zookeeper in the same web server, they must be installed on a Docker container. I have deployed it and I have a fresh Solr 9.6, and Zookeeper 3.9.2., running. I have read this page about Solr in Docker, but It doesn't clarify me the next questions:

After install it, I can't open Solr admin page, neither from https://public_machine_ip:8983/Solr/Admin nor from ssh terminal via wget to https://localhost:8983/Solr/Admin. It always gets connection refused, but my firewall (Plesk) allow this port.

I want Solr can only be accessed by local pages. I have set SOLR_JETTY_HOST and SOLR_ZK_EMBEDDED_HOST variables to 127.0.0.1., and I restarted both containers.


I have checked both containers are running. I have two questions:
a) How could I access to solr admin page?
b) How could I set LANG to spanish? I have tried with es_es:UTF-8 but without success.

How are you running your containers? Have you forwarded the relevant ports with docker (-p option as shown)? You can bind the forwarded port to localhost on your server, so that 2: becomes correct. The other settings will only be relevant inside your container.

docker ps reports solr 127.0.0.1:32774->8983/tcp, and zookeeper 127.0.0.1:32771->2181/tcp,....
